# Rider, IntelliJ: how to put the cursor after the semicolon using Tab key

Tags: rider

While using Visual Studio for coding, I use tab key for navigating in code, including to put the cursor after semicolon.
I began to use Rider, but I couldn't use tab key for doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the answer I received from Rider help:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search_Structural_Navigation.html